# Wordpress landing page for asp.net core mvc azure web app

Tags: wordpress, azure, asp.net-core, azure-webapps

Is it possible to have my landing page (root url www.xxx.com) be a wordpress site hosted in azure and also have a azure asp.net core mvc web app live together? the asp.net website would start from a login page that I can redirect from the wp landing page (www.xxx.com/login).

If possible, can someone direct me on how to accomplish this? I've done some searching around, but haven't found anything concrete.

Comment: Are you looking for a redirection code from Asp.net MVC website after successful login to some external web app hosted in azure(wordpress) ?  Is this the question?

Comment: https://github.com/iolevel/wpdotnet-sdk

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWholeOfWordPressCompiledToNETCoreAndANuGetPackageWithPeachPie.aspx

Comment: @FalcoAlexander Thanks! Let me do some investigating on that!